# java8 generic<T> return type for varargs method broken?

Tags: generics, javacompiler

I am facing a problem after I have switched from Java6 to Java8.

Suddenly a

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.base/[Ljava.lang.Object;**

is thrown.

It seems that the generic type  cannot be matched to the varargs argument of java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Object obj, Object... args).

Due to the fact that the code is compile clean and only will fail during runtime, this looks really scary for me.
By the way, compiling and executing even with java8 will be successful if source / target definition is < 1.8 !

I have prepared a little JUnit example to get a better understanding:

```java
public class GenericVarArgTest {
private static InnerClass myInnerClass;

@Test
public void testMethodInvocation()
        throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

    doSomething();

    System.out.println("Done .. all fine");
}

private void doSomething() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    myInnerClass = this.new InnerClass();
    Method[] methods = myInnerClass.getClass().getMethods();
    for (Method aktMethod : methods) {
        if (aktMethod.getName().equals("printInteger")) {

            // this will always be okay
            // Integer myParam = getSomething();
            // aktMethod.invoke(myInnerClass, myParam);

            // this is just ok, for source / target level <= 1.7 
            aktMethod.invoke(myInnerClass, getSomething());
        }
    }
}

public static <T> T getSomething() {

    final T result = (T) Integer.valueOf(1);

    System.out.println("getSomething will return <T> : " + result);
    return result;
}

public class InnerClass {

    public String printInteger(final Integer aInteger) {
        final String result = "Integer: " + aInteger;
        System.out.println("Will return : " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have set up this little test with maven using this pom:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.test.java</groupId>
<artifactId>compiler-test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>compiler test</name>
<description>Test the different compiler results    </description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <project.java.source.level>${java.version}</project.java.source.level>
    <project.java.target.level>${java.version}</project.java.target.level>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.java.source.level}</source>
                <target>${project.java.target.level}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If you execute this pom with

> mvn clean compile test -Djava.version=**1.6**

everything is fine.
But executing it with

> mvn clean compile test -Djava.version=**1.8**

will result in a ClassCastException.

Any hint why this behavior has changed. Is this a bug (or was it a bug until 1.8)?
Thanks a lot for any explanation.

Comment: Java 10 is the current version. Maybe if you bring your java up to date the problem will go away.

Comment: Hi, even with the current latest Java 10 version I have this issue. Running with Java 10 but setting source and target version of the compiler to java 1.7 still works under Java 10 as well.
Unfortunately our code will run in an Java8 environment and i cannot change source and target version :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have still not concluded about the actual root cause. But just so that I could provide you with some help, this behaviour is not there in all the jdk8 releases. I tested the code with **jdk 8u60** it worked fine (no `ClassCastException` thrown). However, testing it on **jdk 8u144** and **jdk 8u181** (the latest available at the time of writing this answer) resulted in a `ClassCastException`. So, in the meantime, to bypass this issue you can consider downgrading to an earlier jdk8 release which does not portray the buggy behaviour.

Comment: Hi, tanks for your answer.
Unluckily I do not have control over the runtime Java Version my code is running in, but it is quite interesting that early Java 8 runtimes do not show up this Exception.

I am trying to find out if this is a kind of Bug in java or if I can find any release note about this behavior.
Because this Exception occurs in (latest) Java 8, Java 9 and Java 10 I fear it is a feature not a bug :-(

Any further ideas / hints are very welcome to this topic.